# Monthly aggregation of usage information in an accounting system

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am working in an accounting system that receives (by means of a queue) usage events about different elements that can be created (with a type), modified and destroyed. I can have ~1000000 events each month.

At the end of the month, the system has to aggregate the information to generate a report containing how many time a given element has been used. I am sure I will need to perform daily aggregations as well.

It is clearer with an example. These are the kind of events I receive:

```
{event: "create", date: "2013/01/01", element_id: 1, element_type: "L"}
{event: "modify", date: "2013/02/05", element_id: 1, element_type: "XL"}
{event: "modify", date: "2013/02/07", element_id: 1, element_type: "L"}
{event: "destroy", date: "2013/02/08", element_id: 1}
```

And this should be the result for "February":

```
-- from 2013/02/01 to 2013/02/05 + 2013/02/07 to 2013/02/08
{element: "1", element_type: "L", units: "6 days" }
-- from 2013/02/05 to 2013/02/07
{element: "1", element_type: "XL", units: "2 days" }
```

My main concern is **how to keep track of elements that where created in previous intervals** (for example 2 years ago) and are still not destroyed in an efficient way.

Are you aware of any algorithm that could fit this problem? I've been thinking about a map-reduce process but I am not sure how could it fit (filter by month, keep track of elements created in previous months, etc). Any idea is welcome.

I am currently using nodejs and mongodb to store the events if that helps, but I could use java and/or mysql if that supposes any advantage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to go about solving this problem that it is hard to give you a good answer. What I will do is give you some suggestions.

1. Like you have already mentioned build a mapreduce, or even better use the new aggregation framework if your data allows. That is a fair amount of data so maybe you need to aggregate more frequently.
2. Aggregate more frequently, say daily, and store this data in a new collection, or different datastore, adding to it with your daily scheduled aggregation task. This way at the end of the month you can just make one simple query for the monthly data.
3. Hadoop!

If #2 seems like a good route for you, you might want to look into using a star schema for storing your daily aggregations, and perhaps storing in a RDBMS. Not only will it be nice for you to build tools with, but there are many products on the market that will hook up nicely to star/snowflake schema data for analysis.

Sounds like a fun project!